# How to handle classes which don't differ from abstract superclass and require no table

Tags: eclipse, inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I have some classes which don't really differ from the abstract superclass, and so dont require their own table.  I am using the Spring Roo.

I have a Task superclass mapped to a Task table, and am using the Inheritance.Joined inheritance model.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

privileged aspect Task_Roo_Jpa_Entity {

declare @type: Task: @Entity;

declare @type: Task: @Table(schema = "ADMIN_DIRECT", name = "TASK");

declare @type: Task: @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
private BigDecimal Task.id;

public BigDecimal Task.getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void Task.setId(BigDecimal id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

I have some subclasses which do not differ from the abstract super class, and so do not need a dedicated table in the database, while others do differ from the superclass and so have a dedicated table.

I can get persistence to work by doing this in my subclasses which do not differ from the abstract class. I.e. create a subclass which Extends Task and annotate as below (note the table name TASK is actually the superclass table):

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "ADMIN_DIRECT", name = "TASK")

public class ExpensesTask extends Task {


}
```

This persists an entity in the TASK superclass table with a DTYPE column labelled "ExpensesTask" as the discriminator value.

So it appears to work, although Eclipse is raising errors stating that

```
ExpensesTask" is mapped, but is not included in any persistence unit ... JPA Problem
```

If I let Roo take over as I do in my "proper" subclasses of task, then persistence seems to go through the motions and then fail silently (nothing persisted, no errors raised):

i.e. this doesn't work

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooDbManaged(automaticallyDelete = true)
@RooJpaActiveRecord(versionField = "", table = "TASK", schema = "ADMIN_DIRECT")
public class ExpensesTask extends Task {

}  




import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

privileged aspect ExpensesTask_Roo_Jpa_Entity {

    declare @type: ExpensesTask: @Entity;

   declare @type: ExpensesTask: @Table(schema = "ADMIN_DIRECT", name = "TASK");    
}
```

Would be interested to know the correct way to map this inheritance situation when there is no need to differentiate the subclass from abstract superclass.

I could always create an "ExpensesTask" table with nothing but an "ID" field in it, so the Roo method works as for my other "subclass with table" classes, but as I have a working version (albeit with some Eclipse complaints) I am not sure if thats a bit of a "fudge".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the table to be the superclass' table in the subclass is the current support way of doing this in EclipseLink, and does work.  (technically JPA does not allow a class to not have a table in JOINED inheritance, but EclipseLink does).

Another method of accomplishing the same thing would be to let it default a table and use a DescriptorCustomizer to clear the descriptor's tables to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks...DescriptorCustomizer is beyond me at this point. So would you advise against creating tables with just an ID column to overcome the eclipse complaints?